# Magento 2.2.1 XML Validation issue

Tags: xml, upgrade, magento-2.2.1

I have upgraded Magento version from 2.1.4 to 2.2.1. Upgrade was successfull but once after Upgrade when i open homepage it's showing following error,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 408
```

Can anyone please suggest how to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, Issue has been fixed. It was custom module having the bug in xml layout (Static text was there).

`checkout cart index` instead of `<!--         checkout cart index-->`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this error: I removed one by one xml files, till I found in which one is the problem, and I found it in one of the extensions. Hope this is helpful for you :)